# Move root of character without changing the other bones position

Tags: animation, parent, rigify

I'm very new to animation, and I've some troubles to make my character walk (rigged using rigify). I tried to use a walk cycle generated by AnimBox, but my character ended up sliding a lot (even when changing the speed, I guess the walk cycle of AnimBox was not of great quality), and I guess this is not usable for more complex moves like stairs... So I tried to animate manually my character by fixing the root bone (this way I'm sure I've no sliding). So far is works nicely, but I've an issue: my character goes away from the root:

[image]

As I would like my character to come back to its rest position at the end, I need to ensure the root is below my character, not behind. But I can't find how to move the root without also moving my character bones (I can manually try to approximate it, but it's very tedious).

PS: if you have tricks to easily animate walks/plugins without sliding, including potentially more complex walks, please let me know ^^'

Comment: It's not perfect, but I've found [Rigify Animbox Addon](https://blender-addons.org/rigify-animbox-addon/) a useful tool for starting my walk cycle animations.  Most walk cycles are "in place", by the way.  The character appears to walk but moves forward are followed by moves backwards so the object doesn't move.

Comment: Seconding that- walk cycles are in place, and then you just move the root

Comment: @MartyFouts Ok thanks. I did try rigify animbox, but I don't know why when I was moving my character the character was sliding (sometimes backward, sometimes forward depending on the time of the animation). So I guess the animation given by rigify was not good enough.

Comment: @josephhansen Hum thanks, I guess I'll need to create my own walk cycle then. But for more complex animations (e.g. stairs), I guess it's impossible to do it with a root constantly moving no? Also, I'm confused: is it best practice to move the root in pose position, or to move the whole rig in object mode?

Comment: It's not impossible, but it's usually done by doing an in-place walk cycle and then using the Non-Linear Animation editor to combine moving the root as one action with the walk cycle as another.  And yes, it's tedious to work things out so there's no sliding. Here is the [teaser ad](https://youtu.be/K6lYYgLKH04) for a very good animation course, if you'd like to learn from tutorials; but it isn't cheap.

Comment: Whoo, that seems like a lot of work. Can't understand why nobody created a more robust way to avoid sliding. Like I guess it should be doable to define for any character a few "actionable reference objects" which describe which parts touches the ground or not (and therefore should not slide): then blender could automatically compute the position of the root to ensure these reference object never slide when they are "active" (i.e. on ground).